# How do you find where a macro is from in Julia?

Tags: julia

How do you find out where a macro is from in Julia. I'm looking at someone's code and they're using an `@debug("string")` macro. There are no using statements in the particular file that would tell me where it's loaded from, so I assume it's loaded form somewhere else in the code.

I might guess at the debug module for Julia, but it doesn't seem like it's being used that way, it seems like it's being used more for logging, so I'm a bit unsure of how to track it down through the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A macro location can be obtained using the `@which` macro, this is a feature introduced in 0.5.

```
julia> @which @printf("%0.2f", 1/3)
@printf(args...) at printf.jl:1178
```

Similar to `@which`, you can use `@edit` to open the source file and `@functionloc` to get the function location programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

You can go to help mode in the Julia repl by keyboard shortcut **shfit+?**

```
help?> @debug
  No documentation found.

  @debug is a macro.

  # 1 method for macro "@debug":
  @debug(msg...) at /home/guo/.julia/v0.5/Logging/src/logging_macros.jl:11
```

I guess the marco `@debug` is probably from the package [`Logging.jl`](https://github.com/kmsquire/Logging.jl).